# How is this sum equal in unsigned binary and twos complement binary?

Tags: binary, twos-complement, bit-representation

I'm reading through a computer architecture book and came across the following:

*Assume you have a 8-bit cell. So there are 256 possible integer values. Non-negatives run from 0 to 127. Assuming two's complement binary representation, what is the sum of 97 + 45?*

Unsigned is clearly 142, you can do it as 97 + 45 in decimal, or:

```
0110 0001
0010 1101 ADD
--------------
1000 1110
```

But when you perform two's complement, you take that result (`1000 1110`) and determine that it is negative since the sign bit is 1. Then take the one's complement of it:

```
NOT 1000 1110 = 0111 0001
```

Then determine its two's complement:

```
0111 0001
0000 0001 ADD
--------------
0111 0010
```

This number is `114` but because our original number had a `1` in the sign bit, it's `-114`.

**Question(s):**

Why go through all the trouble of having the two's complement to find `-114`? Since 97 and 45, why not just find the sum of the two positive integers as an unsigned value which fits within the range of an 8-bit cell (`1111 1111` being `255`). Is it just because the question asks for the two's complement?

Is `-114` equivalent to `142`? I believe so if you take the two's complement number line, yo get `142-256` which is `-114`. From this, I dont understand why you would want to even use two's complement if you are summing two positive values!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 1's complement just means *flip all the bits*, a 2's complement means *negate the value*. So 1's complement for 8-bit results effectively in `255 - x` and 2's in `256 - x`. You achieve the result of a 2's complement by doing a 1's complement and adding `1`.

The `142` in 8-bit *is* equal to `-114`. Don't get too confused about it.

Comment: So if I declare `int x = 97; int y = 45; int z = x + y;` I get `142` even though I never declare any as `unsigned`. Does the system determine that what I need is `unsigned` addition?

Comment: You also say `142` in 8-bit is equal to `-114` in decimal. But `1000 1110` in 8-but `unsigned` is `142`, `-114` if `signed`. What confuses me is why you would ever want the `signed` version if not using negative values. Sure this is just an example, but you could never return decimal `-114` and say that is the sum of `95 + 45`, it's just wrong...right?

Comment: @datta `int` usually represents 32 or 64 bit values. Try it again with `char` if you have a C/C++ compiler handy. Try this: `char x=100; x+= 30; cout << (int)x;`

Comment: Even still, if I add two positive values, I would think they would never need to be `signed`. Only if I wanted to say add `95 + (-45)` would I need `signed` byte.

Comment: This is why most programming languages offer `unsigned` prefix. It's left to the programmer how data values should be interpreted.

Comment: Perl e.g. doesn't know unsigned. If you had two positive integers and added them, you never could produce a negative result.

Comment: Humor me if you will. Lets say I do have an 8-bit value (not a typical `int` of 32- or 64-bit). I want to add `97 + 45`. Lets assume its `signed`. Well `142` would put us beyond the range of the 8-bit (ending at `127`) so does it return `-114`?

Comment: @datta If it's signed, yes.